# Uniform convergence of $f_n= \frac{nxe^{-nx}}{n^2x^2+1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I'm asked to determine if the following sequences converges and how:
$$f_n= \frac{nxe^{-nx}}{n^2x^2+1}$$
It's easy to see that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n=0$ and so $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f=0$. To see if the convergence is also uniform I have to evaluate
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_{\mathbb{R}}||f_n(x)-f(x)||= \lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_{\mathbb{R}}||\frac{nxe^{-nx}}{n^2x^2+1}||$$
so I tried to study $f_n'(x)$ but this lead nowhere (I suppose I don't have to use the algebraic formula for finding roots of polynomials of degree $3$):
$$f_n'(x)=0 \iff \frac{(ne^{-nx}-n^2xe^{-nx})(n^2x^2+1)-2n^2x(nxe^{-nx})}{(n^2x^2+1)^2}=0 \iff n^3x^3+n^2x^2+nx+1=0$$
and I'm stuck.
Can I have a help, please?

**EDIT**

I'm asked if and where the convergence is uniform.

Comment: Since $f_n(x)=f_1(nx)$, you have that $$\sup||f_n(x)|| = \sup ||f_1(x)|| \neq 0$$ since the supremum of $f_1$ is a constant which does not depend on $n$, the convergence is not uniform, without need of computing anything.

Comment: This is actually brilliant, but I think you should have more experience then what I have to notice this at the first sight. May I ask you for a standard procedure? By the way, awesome answer.

Comment: The problem makes no sense unless you tell us what is the domain of your functions,

Comment: I'm asked to study if and where the convergence is uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mistake In your third degree equation
$$n^3x^3+n^2x^2+nx-1=0$$

here is an other way;

$(f_n)$ converges pointwise to zero at $[0,+\infty)$.

for $x<0$, $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(x)=-\infty$$

on the other hand, for $n>0$

$$|f_n(\frac 1n)-0|=\frac{1}{2e}$$

thus
$$\sup_{x\ge 0}|f_n(x)-0|\ge \frac{1}{2e}$$
the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the convergence is uniform only in $(0, +\infty)$, yes?

Comment: @AlbertoAndrenucci No, it is uniform at $[a,+\infty)$ for any $a>0$.